# Why is HTML span stacking vertically?

Tags: html, css

On my website I have two SPANS : "services" and "products" in the top right corner (in the gray strip). For some reason they are being stacked vertically, where I would expect them to align horizontally, since SPANS are just a markup that marksup text inside a text block.

Snippet :

```
<div id="access">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>services </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>products</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This CSS is the problem i think

```
#access {
    /* background: #74C20E;
    background: #716417;*/
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background-color:rgb(181, 197, 207);
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;

    width: 1200px;

<!-- width: 940px;
-->
}

#access .menu-header,
div.menu {

    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 928px;
}
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#access .menu-header li,
div.menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#access a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul li {
    min-width: 180px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
    background: #0f9195;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a,
#access ul ul :hover > a {
    background: #635ba9;
    color: #fff;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#access ul li.current_page_item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-item > a,
#access ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/9uK9L/

Does anyone know why they are being displayed vertically rather than horizontally?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Are you promoting your website?

Comment: You need to provide [a test case](http://sscce.org/) in the question. Linking to an external site is bad form, and since you will probably fix it at some point, it will render the question as nonsense as it will depend on code that no longer exists.

Comment: And to answer your quesion, your spans are in anchors which have `display:block` applied. (http://blue-walrus.com/wp-content/themes/whispy/style.css line 463)

Comment: ok, i will edit the post, remove reference to my website, and paste in from one of the solutions instead.

Comment: sorry guys . I've fixed up the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`span` elements are inline by default, unless overridden and they are still inline on your page. It's their parents the `a` elements that are the problem. The relevant page structure looks like this:

```
<div id="access">
  <div>
    <a href="#">
      <span>services </span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <span>products</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your css you've set

```
#access a{
  display: block;
}
```

This cause the anchors to become block level elements, and stack on top of each other, independently of the behavior of the spans. Simply remove `display: block` from `#access a` and it'll work as expected.

I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with the chrome (or any other one) debugger https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements which will let you inspect your page and narrow these issues down fairly easily just by inspecting an element and eyeballing the styles that are being applied.

Answer (score 2):

change display:block to display:inline-block

```
#access a {
    color: white;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```